# RcppParallel: Converting CharacterMatrix to RMatrix<T>

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Hello Dear Community,

I am learning RcppParallel and have this issue while trying to convert a Rcpp::CharacterMatrix to RcppParallel::RMatrix using following codes:

```
struct CharMatDist : RcppParallel::Worker {
    const RcppParallel::RMatrix<std::string> A; 
    const RcppParallel::RMatrix<std::string> B; 
    const NumericVector w; 
    RcppParallel::RMatrix<double> ret; 
    int n; 

    CharMatDist(CharacterMatrix A, CharacterMatrix B, NumericVector w, NumericMatrix ret)
    : A(A), B(B), w(w), ret(ret) {
        n = B.nrow();
    }

...

}
```

As the gallery suggests, I would expect the convertion to be carried out automatically in A(A) etc. but it is not working and gives me following error:

```
cannot convert 'Rcpp:Matrix<16>::iterator (aka Rcpp::internal::Proxy_iterator<Rcpp::internal::string_proxy<16> >)' to 'char*' in initialization
```

I also tried

```
RMatrix<char>
```

and even manual cast in body but also without success. Where am I doing wrong??

Any suggestions and help would be highly appreciated.

YYA

Comment: Can you please include the rest of your code (the `...`)?

Comment: The rest should kinda calculate some distance measures between each pair of rows in A and B respectively, on which I am still working. According to my tests, the existing codes are already enough to produce the error prefectly. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that `CharacterVector` and `CharacterMatrix` types are really just vectors of `SEXP`s -- more specifically, a `CharacterVector` wraps a `STRSXP`, whose contents is an array of `SEXP`s (of runtime type `CHARSXP`). Unfortunately, knowing these details is necessary when interacting with R's character types.

I have no idea if this will work, but if it did, you'd want to use something like an `RMatrix<SEXP>`, which would (presumedly) map over the underlying `CHARSXP`s inside the matrix -- wherein you could access the underlining `const char*` string with `CHAR`.

The `RMatrix` class is not 'smart' enough to directly provide access to the underlying strings in this case, unfortunately, so I believe you will have to unwrap it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. After trying out your suggestion and more possibilities like accessing RMatrix with iterators(, which actually works), I still cannot convert one from CharacterVector or -Matrix. So I have decided simply to code the characters in numericals. Maybe we could hope for an improvement in the updates to come. :D

Comment: An important note from the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/parallel-matrix-transform/)

> Note also that we use the RMatrix<double> type for accessing the matrix. This is because this code will execute on a background thread where it’s not safe to call R or Rcpp APIs. The RMatrix class is included in the RcppParallel package and provides a lightweight, thread-safe wrapper around R matrixes.