# How to create thread-safe wrap of Rcpp::CharacterMatrix with RcppParallel?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, rcppparallel

I have a task where I need to process a large matrix (millions of rows, hundreds of columns) of character strings.  Each row operation is independent.  As such, I would like to exploit some parallel computing to increase the speed of the overall project.

If I build `myWorker` for numeric matrices, as follows, I'm able to compile the code without errors

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppParallel)]]
#include <RcppParallel.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <string.h>

struct myWorker : public RcppParallel::Worker
{
  // input
  const RcppParallel::RMatrix<double> input;
  int version;

  // output
  RcppParallel::RMatrix<double> outmat;

  // initialization
  myWorker(const Rcpp::NumericMatrix input, int version, Rcpp::NumericMatrix outmat) 
    : input(input), version(version), outmat(outmat) {}

  // the operator
  void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end) {
    // do stuff
  }
};
```

However, when I set the input matrix and initialization to use
`Rcpp::CharacterMatrix` I get compile errors.

```
In instantiation of ‘RcppParallel::RMatrix<T>::RMatrix(const Source&) [with
Source = Rcpp::Matrix<16>; T = <typehere>]

R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/RcppParallel/include/RcppParallel/RMatrix.h:198:28:
error: cannot convert ‘Rcpp::Matrix<16>::iterator {aka
Rcpp::internal::Proxy_Iterator<Rcpp::internal::string_proxy<16> >}’ to
‘std::basic_string<char>*’ in initialization
         ncol_(source.ncol())
```

Combinations I've tried with `myWorker(const Rcpp::NumericMatrix input`

```
const RcppParallel::RMatrix<std::string> input;
const RcppParallel::RMatrix<char> input;
const RcppParallel::RMatrix<char*> input;
const RcppParallel::RMatrix<char**> input;
const RcppParallel::RMatrix<char32_t> input;
```

The pointers were a bad idea.  The other options lead to a common error noted
above.

A very similar question was asked
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105531/rcppparallel-converting-charactermatrix-to-rmatrixt/29115437).

Is there a simple way to wrap a `Rcpp::NumericMatrix` with
`RcppParallel::RMatrix` for thread-safe work with a character matrix?

**EDIT**

More details on the task:

The `imput` matrix consists of ICD-9-CM or ICD-10-CM codes which need to be
compared to sets of codes to determine classifications.  There are millions of
rows, hundreds of columns, and about a dozen classifications.

An small example in pure R would be:

```
classification_1 <-
  c("99680", "99688", "99689", "V421", "V422", "V426", "V5391", "4697", "5051",
    "5059", "5280", "5282", "4103", "0091", "0092", "0093")
classification_2 <-
  c("14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "23", "V4281", "V4282", "0010", "9925")

icd_codes <- 
  structure(c("5282", "3320", "4100", "0234", "V426", "3895", "3592", 
              "5651", "0397", "V5302", "5675", "0092", "V461", "4697", "5571", 
              "3776", "9964", "9702", "3583", "8607", "99661", "3767", "3129", 
              "3182", "5503", "5285", "4641", "6861", "3351", "2751", "76511", 
              "V446", "34581", "7472", "5190", "9723", "28801", "0010", "8103", 
              "4270", "9962", "4211", "4242", "34511", "3352", "0372", "76492", 
              "5675", "284", "4281", "3314", "0681", "3781", "0152", "3760", 
              "3763", "5597", "4399", "V5351", "8108", "3994", "4581", "V460", 
              "5533", "8137", "99663", "4210", "741", "5722", "8949", "76412", 
              "5569", "5674", "99667", "7707", "3753", "8606", "V553", "5051", 
              "2884", "5059", "7711", "8136", "5673", "7373", "2821", "5993", 
              "3776", "2822", "4274", "3789", "0371", "3591", "76523", "5722", 
              "V56", "V445", "2359", "4243", "99683"), .Dim = c(5L, 20L))

apply(icd_codes, 1,
      function(x) {
        c(class1 = as.integer(any(x %in% classification_1)),
          class2 = as.integer(any(x %in% classification_2)))
      })
```

Each row the `icd_codes` object could be evaluated in parallel.  Since I have a
working single-threaded C++ version of the above working, I was hoping to use
RcppParallel to improve the overall speed of the work, and critically, do so in a
way that is as close to OS independent as possible.  The group I'm working with
consists of Windows, OSX, and Linux users.

Comment: It all depends what you do in each task/thread ... can you elaborate ?

Comment: @RomainFrancois, I've edited the question to include more details on my objective.

Answer (score 0):

For an extremely fast Rcpp-based matrix algebra solution to the co-morbidity classification problem, see my package [icd](https://jackwasey.github.io/icd), particularly the PDF article sent to JSS on the [methodology](https://jackwasey.github.io/icd/articles/efficiency.pdf).

It'll never be fast with string processing, as you'll quickly find out when profiling, no matter how much higher-level optimization you do.